# How do I get rid BitLocker of the system drive if I can't even login to Windows?

Tags: windows-10, boot, security, password-recovery

I put my system drive on BitLocker.

I don't  have TPM. I have to enter a password.

Due to unrelated reason, the system cannot boot anymore.

And it's very annoying that it reboot again reboot again often with me having to enter password or recovery key for the drive.

How do I turn BitLocker off from, let’s say, Windows Recovery.

I cannot login to Windows.

Comment: You could try putting it in another system but typically you have to disable BitLocker protection from within that installation of Windows since the process requires you to rewrite the data. Sounds like the drive has seen better days

Comment: You state you *were* able to log in, at one time. Keep trying, because you need to open the Windows session in BitLocker to remove BitLocker, or to salvage files.

Comment: I found another way

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I did it.

basically I unlock using the recovery key

Then I go to command prompt and type

```
x:>manage-bde -off f:
```

Here, f: is the drive where I think the windows is. X is a virtual drive that windows create in recovery mode I think?

Not really sure.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct procedure and the system drive is often mounted as f: in the recovery environment. Now see if it has completed using manage-bde -status f: (or c:)

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways:
If you have password or recovery key, you can refer [this article](https://www.manageengine.com/products/os-deployer/help/how-to-disable-bitlocker-encryption.html) to turn off bitlocker. Windows Command Prompt method can be used for offline system recovery via like using Windows Advanced Boot or Windows PE (you can find it in the installation media).

Another way if you lost bitlocker key you can look for professional data recovery companies or tools to try to rescue your data, but if you don’t remember the password at all, the cost is very high based on technical principles.

Finally, if you are willing to give up your data, you can consider making a disk image copy to reserve the opportunity for future decryption and format your hard disk to reinstall the operating system.
In fact, I have already reinstall multiple computers OS due to Windows 10 bitlocker automatic encryption, so individual users do not recommend using bitlocker because the importance of the data is often greater than the confidentiality.